# The differences between aws elasticbeanstalk and EB CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, command-line-interface

The two commands `aws elasticbeanstalk` and `eb` appear to be alternative ways of doing the same things. They appear to have slightly different syntax, for example `aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment` but `eb create`.

And yet the output of the help pages (`aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment help` and `eb create --help`) are sufficiently far that they seem to be developed separately.

What is the difference between `aws elasticbeanstalk` and `eb` when they are installed on macOS using `brew install awscli` and (inside a venv) `pip install awsebcli`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And yet the output of the help pages (aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment help and eb create --help) are sufficiently far that they seem to be developed separately.

You are correct, they are completely different, but they are both CLIs. `aws` is essentially more comparable to the AWS SDKs. i.e. if I am not wrong, for every Beanstalk AWS SDK operation there is an AWS CLI command, whereas every `eb` command is a combination of multiple AWS SDK commands.

The `aws elasticbeanstalk` command comes from the AWSCLI, whereas `eb` comes from the EBCLI/AWSEBCLI.

`eb create` is quite a heavy command. It creates an application version for you, stores it at an S3 location, performs necessary permissions checking, enables integration with CodeCommit and CodeBuild, allows specifying configuration template names to base your environment on, supports creation of environments inside VPCs, etc, among other things, and then, of course, creates an environment. In this sense, it is the CLI equivalent of the Beanstalk console in the browser.

`aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment`, however, merely creates an environment. You need to have had uploaded your app version to S3 prior to executing the command.

1. In general, `eb` operations are usually what you need, but the `aws` operations have their time and place too.
2. `eb` operations are tied to specific applications and require the directory in which they are being executed to be [`eb init`-ed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html), whereas `aws` operations are standalone operations that can be executed from any computer from any directory.

> ... installed on macOS using brew install awscli and (inside a venv) pip install awsebcli?

As for *what* the two commands install is concerned -- the `brew install ...` version might not always install the latest version of `eb`. As of today, it looks like the [homebrew](https://github.com/davidcelis/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/aws-elasticbeanstalk.rb) is pointing to a fairly old version of the EBCLI.

I assume your question is about `brew install awsebcli` vs `pip install awsebcli` inside virtualenvs. Essentially, the `brew install ...` method is supposed to make it easier for MacOS users to install `eb` easily. This is not ideal, IMHO, because it pollutes the system/Library namespace -- personally, I'd like to keep my packages compartmentalized for which `virtualenv` provides me the ability.

Comment: A [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106848/what-is-the-difference-between-awscli-and-awsebcli/47276695#answer-47276695)

Comment: `eb` has several serious flaws, like using virtualenv instead of standard venv. Also some of the critical bugs [haven't been fixed](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/issues/59) since 2019 till now, so I'd better use standard `aws elasticbeanstalk`, it seems to be much better maintained